# get Routing/Binding key in rabbitmq

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

I have two queues, two binding/routing keys, I would like to write a conditional statement in consumer based on routing/binding key, how to get their values?

```js
var amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');
//const mongoose = require('mongoose');


var args = ['user','nouser'];

amqp.connect('amqp://localhost', function(err, conn) {
  conn.createChannel(function(err, ch) {
    var ex = 'logs';

    ch.assertExchange(ex, 'direct', {durable: false});

    ch.assertQueue('', {exclusive: true}, function(err, q) {
      console.log(" [*] Waiting for messages in %s. To exit press CTRL+C");
    
      args.forEach(function(type) {
        ch.bindQueue(q.queue, ex, type);
      });
  
      ch.consume(q.queue, function(msg, res) {
        if(msg.content) {
          console.log(" Received %s", msg.content,q.queue);

        }
      }, {noAck: true});
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Maybe you would do some topic routing, see https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-javascript.html

Answer (score 2):

The `msg` object in the handler for channel.consume contains a `fields` object, which itself contains a `routingKey` field.
So in short:

```
ch.consume(q.queue, function(msg, res) {
    if(msg.content) {
      console.log(" Received %s", msg.content,q.queue);
      if (msg.fields.routingKey === <your condition>) {
        // Handle condition
      }
    }
  }, {noAck: true});
```